# Add Live USB into Software & Updates

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I downloaded the Ubuntu ISO from internet and used Rufus to create the USB boot.
However, Ubuntu can not load my Wifi driver and my Ethernet is broken. that's mean I can't access to the internet right now.
In the **Additional Drivers** it have my driver, however I can not enabled it because of no internet access.

Can I add the USB source to **System Settings > Software & Updates**? Nowadays who use DVD??